# Jquery: Problem with keyboard navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard, navigation

I use this script to navigate with keyboard arrow keys. But the problem is that i can't trigger click.

```
<script>
$(document).keyup(function(e){
    switch (e.keyCode){
        case 39:
        if( $(".imgnav-next").attr("href")){
            $(".imgnav-next").trigger("click");
        }
        break;
        case 37:
        if( $(".imgnav-prev").attr("href")){
            $(".imgnav-prev").trigger("click");
        }
    break;
    }
});
</script>
```

This is the html part with navigation:

```
<div class="imgnav-prev-container">
    <a href="prev.html" class="imgnav-prev">Next pic</a>
</div>
<div class="imgnav-next-container">
    <a href="next.html" class="imgnav-next">Previous pic</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
$(document).keyup(function(e){        
    switch (e.keyCode){                                                                                                                     
        case 39:                                                                                                                            
        if( $(".imgnav-next").attr("href")){      
            window.location = $(".imgnav-next").attr("href");       
        }                                                                                                                                   
        break;                                                                                                                              
        case 37:                                                                                                                            
        if( $(".imgnav-prev").attr("href")){      
            window.location = $(".imgnav-prev").attr("href");       
        }                                                                                                                                   
    break;                                                                                                                                  
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's actually clicking, it just doesn't seem to do anything because you don't have anything binded to your `a` tags that says it got clicked. Also I don't think it's allowed to do fake clicking in browsers using JS, I mean, like the same behavior when you literally click it with your mouse and goes to the URL. You can code to make it `click` it but it won't go to the `href` like when you literally click it. You can however fake the action by something like:

```
  `window.location.href = $(".imgnav-next").attr("href");`
```